# Access control in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In the documentation of BigQuery, it has only three types of sources: organization, project and dataset. Roles and permissions are on these resources.My question is is there any way to define an access control to a particular table in a dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot define access control on table. Only down to dataset!
At the same time there is a way to define [`row-level`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#row-level-permissions) access

Yet, another option for you (depends on specific use case) would potentially be [`Protecting Data with Cloud KMS Keys`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/customer-managed-encryption) - this will not control access but rather ability to see actual data vs. encrypted

Answer (score 2):

With BigQuery you can define read access up to a per-row level:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#row-level-permissions

With that said, going to a per-row or per-table level access will take a lot more work (involving authorized views) than working the native project/dataset access controls.